# Waveshare e-paper demo not working - Raspberry Pi Zero W 1.1

Tags: hat, eink

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W 1.1 and I bought this e-paper HAT and monitor combo from [waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/product/displays/5.83inch-e-paper-hat-c.htm)
I have Installed Raspberry Pi OS headless and configured everything according to this official [wiki](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5.83inch_e-Paper_HAT_(B))
Including updating the OS, enabling SPI, installing dependencies, and downloading the official test script (located [here](https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper)) but nothing happens on the screen :(

I'm looking for any advice on what might I be doing wrong or ways to continue debugging my problem.

Comment: If you had followed the instructions it should be working.  So either you haven't followed the instructions or the display is broken.  Could you list the steps you have taken and the result of each step?

Comment: Or the instructions are out of date or don't apply to your use case. have you contacted the manufacturer or supplier?

Comment: Update: When connecting the RP to the HAT with wires, rather than with the HAT 40 pin connector, it works. How can I find where is the issue, the board or the HAT?